# estou tentando consumir uma api no js via get pelo axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, axios

Estou tentando consumir uma API no `js` via get pelo `axios`, API que contém um parâmetro `apikey`, como o código deve ficar?

como estou tentando fazer:

```
axios.get('url', {params{apikey:'chave_api_key'}})
.then(function(resposta){
console.log(resposta)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [API do Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api), você deve passar um objeto de configuração como segundo argumento, contendo a propriedade `params` com os parâmetros que você desejar passar.

Ficando assim:

```js
axios.get('/user', {
  params: {
    apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
  }
})
  .then((data) => {
    // Do stuff.
  })
  .catch(() => alert('Houve um erro!');
```